# How can I dismiss the parent view controller after the second view controller is launched?

Tags: swift, macos, viewcontroller, dismiss

I am working on an OSX app in swift which programmatically clicks a button to launch a view controller. I would like to dismiss the initial view controller programatically.

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var button: NSButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        button.performClick(nil)


        self.dismissViewController(self)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **1.)** Why do you need to dismiss the parent `ViewController`?  **2.)** What have you tried so far? What does your code look like?

Comment: I need to dismiss the parent viewcontroller because it serves no purpose after the second controller is launched 2) I have tried self.dismisscontroller(self) and different cominations of this.

Comment: I don't think you'd need to _programmatically click a button_ to move to a new `ViewController`. Moving to a new VC can be done without the use of a button. Also, I'm pretty sure you wouldn't need to dismiss a VC if you're moving to a new one.

Comment: Both of them are a part of the requirements for the application so I'd appreciate if you could share the answer if you know the answer to this.

Comment: You do not dismiss a view controller when moving to a new one. That is redundant.

Comment: wouldn't it make it a much cleaner application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your button isn't actually performing `dismissViewController()`. You're actually calling this method in your `viewDidLoad()`. It's also worth mentioning that you might want to try `self.view.window?.close()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Just to upgrade the previous answer

`self.view.window?.close()` doesn't work in swift 4 you might want to try the code below.

```
self.view.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```